# TWebbrowser causes AV - what to look for

Tags: delphi, access-violation, twebbrowser

I have a TWebbroser on a form wher I want to hide the scrollbars

On WebBrowser1DownloadComplete I put WebBrowser1.OleObject.document.body.scroll:='no'; 
But this results in an AV.
If I click continue I can see that the scrollbars are actually removed, so the code must be the right one to use.

What I am trying to do is to show a page from Google Maps with a lot of markers that I add. This page needs to be printed on an A4 page but it is to big to print directly from the TWebbrowser (or at least I can't get it to work). So I save it as an JPG image and loads that on another form, prints it using DevExpress printingsystem on A4 page with the headers and footers I want.
All is working like I want it to except the removal of the scrollbars.

For accessing Google Maps I use the gmLibrary from http://www.cadetill.com/gmlib/ - very nice lib and it has a pricetag I like.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in the DocumentComplete event to remove the AV.

The IE HTML/CSS tricks to remove the scrollbars will not work reliable if the control is embedded. To realy remove the scrollbar you have to inherit the TWebBrowser with the IDocHostUIHandler interface. In GetHostInfo you have to set at least the DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO flag.

You may consider to use one of the existing descendants like 'Embedded Web Browser Component Pack' (http://www.bsalsa.com/).

Comment: Result := No AV but Scrollbars = Visible;